# How do you Build Random Items with Multiple Variables with Multiple Choices in Python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

What area of Python Documentation should I look into to accomplish the following:

```
npc_gender = ["Male","Female"]
npc_age = # trying to do random integer within a range say 18-80
npc_name_male = ["Arnold","Bob","Charles","David","Edward"]
npc_name_female = ["Annie","Barbara","Courtney","Danielle","Ellen"]
""" Obviously, the names are gender specific for an if/else statement :) """
npc_weight = # trying to figure out how to do range...not sure yet, but still variable.
npc_height = # same a weight...not sure yet.

def create_npc():
    if npc_gender == "Male"
        # select (automatically) one of the npc_name_male[#:] and store.
        return npc_name_male[#:]
    elif npc_gender == "Female"
        # select (automatically) one of the npc_name_female[#:] and store.
    else:
        return
```

Now I am confused...basically, I want the program to create me a character out of a selection of parameters that are already stored in the variables...

Am I headed in the right direction? Thanks in Advance.

Response to Blender:

```
import random
npc_gender = ["Male","Female"]

def create_npc():
    npc_gender_choice = random.choice(npc_gender)
    print(npc_gender_choice)

create_npc()
```

I did this and it helped me understand.  I will continue working on it until I have it all working and then will update the post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `random.choice()` to get a random element:

```
import random

...

choice = random.choice(npc_name_male)
```

Comment: I did this and it helped!  import random
npc_gender = ["Male","Female"]

def create_npc():
    npc_gender_choice = random.choice(npc_gender)
    print(npc_gender_choice)

create_npc()